# Yocto Qt6 build - RM died with SIGABRT

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, yocto

I'm building yocto image (core-image-minimal) with Qt6 on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.2.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.1.4"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "langdale:3e95f268ce04b49ba6731fd4bbc53b1693c21963"
meta-raspberrypi     = "langdale:8e3cbfa598de106a78d9a9e27aa25ded51416896"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-networking      
meta-python          = "langdale:cbbaa82238cd60f08c9b9cb58dde59d5f9318c7b"
meta-qt6             = "6.5:a65fb409f4469c087ae3e23ee80fbb2531f1856e"
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR: libarchive-3.6.2-r0 do_package: Error executing a python function in exec_func_python() autogenerated:



The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:

File: 'exec_func_python() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>

     0001:

 *** 0002:sstate_task_postfunc(d)

     0003:

File: '/home/m/Downloads/yocto/build/../sources/poky/meta/classes-global/sstate.bbclass', lineno: 824, function: sstate_task_postfunc

     0820:

     0821:    omask = os.umask(0o002)

     0822:    if omask != 0o002:

     0823:       bb.note("Using umask 0o002 (not %0o) for sstate packaging" % omask)

 *** 0824:    sstate_package(shared_state, d)

     0825:    os.umask(omask)

     0826:

     0827:    sstateinst = d.getVar("SSTATE_INSTDIR")

     0828:    d.setVar('SSTATE_FIXMEDIR', shared_state['fixmedir'])

File: '/home/m/Downloads/yocto/build/../sources/poky/meta/classes-global/sstate.bbclass', lineno: 679, function: sstate_package

     0675:

     0676:    sstatebuild = d.expand("${WORKDIR}/sstate-build-%s/" % ss['task'])

     0677:    sde = int(d.getVar("SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH") or time.time())

     0678:    d.setVar("SSTATE_CURRTASK", ss['task'])

 *** 0679:    bb.utils.remove(sstatebuild, recurse=True)

     0680:    bb.utils.mkdirhier(sstatebuild)

     0681:    for state in ss['dirs']:

     0682:        if not os.path.exists(state[1]):

     0683:            continue

File: '/home/m/Downloads/yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/utils.py', lineno: 728, function: remove

     0724:        # shutil.rmtree(name) would be ideal but its too slow

     0725:        cmd = []

     0726:        if ionice:

     0727:            cmd = ['ionice', '-c', '3']

 *** 0728:        subprocess.check_call(cmd + ['rm', '-rf'] + glob.glob(path))

     0729:        return

     0730:    for name in glob.glob(path):

     0731:        try:

     0732:            os.unlink(name)

File: '/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py', lineno: 369, function: check_call

     0365:    if retcode:

     0366:        cmd = kwargs.get("args")

     0367:        if cmd is None:

     0368:            cmd = popenargs[0]

 *** 0369:        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

     0370:    return 0

     0371:

     0372:

     0373:def check_output(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):

Exception: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['rm', '-rf', '/home/m/Downloads/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/libarchive/3.6.2-r0/sstate-build-package/']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.



ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/m/Downloads/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/libarchive/3.6.2-r0/temp/log.do_package.121192

ERROR: Task (/home/m/Downloads/yocto/build/../sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/libarchive/libarchive_3.6.2.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1' 

Pseudo log:

path mismatch [5 links]: ino 19665829 db '/home/m/Downloads/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/libarchive/3.6.2-r0/package/usr/src/debug/libarchive/3.6.2-r0/tar/subst.c' req '/home/m/Downloads/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/libarchive/3.6.2-r0/sstate-build-package/packages-split/libarchive-src/usr/src/debug/libarchive/3.6.2-r0/tar/subst.c'.

Setup complete, sending SIGUSR1 to pid 121193.
```

At the same time, Ubuntu crashes:

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This smells like something that could take hours/days to debug, but before spending any time on it, what happens if you do `bitbake -c cleanall libarchive` and then try to build the image again?

Comment: Yes, that helped. Also manually deleting the "sstate-build-package" folder of libarchive helps. Hopefully, it is just a glitch that won't repeat. Thank you